# Puppeteer doesn't work in ubuntu 18 for aws AMI

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-ec2, puppeteer

So, my nodejs-react app uses cheerio and puppeteer to **scrape** data and it works just fine in localhost, but since I deployed it on ec2 AWS, it throws an error as soon as it reaches page.launch.
I have used  https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-aws-lambda and it still didn't make any difference.

Comment: What's the error you are getting? You don't need https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-aws-lambda for running on ec2

Comment: This is the error im getting Failed to launch the browser process!
/home/ubuntu/chegg_back/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-737027/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libX11-xcb.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Try this - https://medium.com/@ssmak/how-to-fix-puppetteer-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libx11-xcb-so-1-c1918b75acc3